# How do I install a specific version of java on Ubuntu

Tags: java, compiling

I am trying to build Android from source and it require Java 1.6 to build. So, I installed OpenJDK version 6. However, when I try to build using the `make` command I get the following message:

```
Your version is: java version "1.6.0_31".
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.
```

Can anyone tell me how do I install the correct version required for building the code?

Thanks!

Edit:

The output of `java -version` is:

```
java version "1.6.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: what is the output of $ java -version

Answer (score 0):

You can get access as well as information regarding why you shouldn't here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html

I have had trouble with java in the past when I had both iced tea and SUN/Oracle versions installed. That looks like the case here. I'm not sure whether this will help in your specific instance but I would remove all java and then reinstall from the oracle archive if you are intent on using a security flawed version. Best of luck!

Comment: Actually, I already downloaded java from that page and installed it. But it doesn't help.